# Mechanism to check if a C++ member is private

Tags: c++, unit-testing, template-meta-programming, private-members

I am writing unit tests for undergraduate students and want to enforce certain members as public or private. I am aware of methods to actually test private members, e.g., `#define private public` or using a friend class, but have not seen anything that would allow me to check exactly if a member is private or not.

A brute force method would be trying a compile and parsing the output error, e.g., look for something like `error: 'foo' is a private member of 'Bar'`, but I am hoping someone will have a better trick!

Comment: Can you give an example input you'd see? I think you're pretty clear about your output - you want to automatically determine that a member which should be private actually is. what compiler are you using?

Comment: You can use clang's AST dump with flag `-ast-dump` and examine if certain member is private

Comment: Unless you use particular features of particular compilers/hosts, your options are limited, other than triggering a compilation error by accessing a member that should be private.   Bear in mind such a test can be - accidentally or deliberately - subverted to give false positives or negatives. Consider what happens if testing code is declared as a `friend` of the class, if the member is `protected` and your test function is a member of a derived class, or if the member is removed.    It might be easier to write a separate script to check by directly parsing the class/struct definition.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to assert that a type `Bar` doesn't have a public member named `foo`, you can write the following test:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto has_public_foo(T const &t) -> decltype(t.foo, true) 
{
    return true;
}

constexpr auto has_public_foo(...) 
{
    return false;
}

static_assert(not has_public_foo(Bar{}), "Public members are bad practice");
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/56j68f).

Comment: It test if certain member is public or not but it does not test if a member is private.

Comment: @Slava Do you mean, as opposed to protected?

Comment: Not only, your test will give false positive if member does not exist at all.

Comment: Yes, true, but it's not clear that those are requirements the OP has.

Comment: "want to enforce certain members as public or private" I think it is pretty clear especially with this: "look for something like error: 'foo' is a private member" And subject says to check if member is private, not if member is not public.

Comment: Please don't test people on "public members are bad practice". They grow up thinking public members are evil and then when there's a situation where a public member would be useful they still follow the dogma you taught them. This is how you end up with every member having a getter and setter function

Comment: @user253751 That's reasonable, but this should be a comment for the OP's question, no? The answer is just a solution for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @user253751: But public members *are* evil. They are glorified global variables. Unless the problem really calls for pure [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure).

Comment: @PeterMortensen (1) No, public members are not global variables (you may be thinking of static members). (2) there is nothing wrong with POD classes, even POD classes that also have helper functions in them. (3) teaching people that "public variables are evil" teaches them that POD classes are evil.

Comment: Nothing wrong with getters and setters. Within reason. If you find yourself writing lots of getsetters, see if you can group some of them inside a class! (Java guy here from the HNQ list).

Comment: @user253751 The key message to deliver to students would be: "There are two kinds of objects. Those that are POD, and those which have their members private. Don't make members public unless you have proven that they should be part of the public interface." But the majority of members should be private, and that should be the default, and I think it's a good idea to teach this default.

Comment: @cs95 There's everything wrong with getters and setters. There is no difference between a public member and a member with the trivial getter and setter. If you rely on such members, you are modelling data, not behavior. A proper object oriented class generally has no need for a getters/setters because it provides functionality at a higher abstraction level. The exceptions to this are few and far between.

Comment: you have a little mistake on the last line of the demo, please remove the `not`

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I still disagree with teaching this. At the very least, this kind of rule should be relegated to a separate class that deals with design, not a class that just teaches the language. Students ***must*** understand that it's not a language rule, but only a guideline, and you ***must*** not give them the impression that it is! Nothing in the language enforces this dichotomy, and it's not unimaginable that you might run into a situation where you want a class that has some POD characteristics and some non-POD characteristics, though I can't think of one OTOH.

Comment: @TigranSahakyan No, it's correct. I want to assert that there *isn't* a particular public member.

Comment: @user253751 I had such a class once. Everything was private, except for the parent pointer. The semantics of the class were defined relative to its parent, but there were absolutely no constraints that were to be enforced about the parent. On the contrary, the whole point of the class was that the user was able to change the parent at will, and have the class do its work relative to that, whatever it may be. Such things are not common, but they exist in real code.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to the OP, but your implementation of `has_public_foo` fails if the `foo` has an `operator,(bool)` (the comma operator) returning something other than bool. `decltype(t.foo, void(), true)` seems like an appropriate fix. This works because you cannot overload an `operator,` to take `void` as an argument.
For a demo, see https://wandbox.org/permlink/m6hywyFLVMaf76Dx

Comment: @MatthiasVegh That's a good point. However, I'm very confident that this is not a concern for the OP :) They are just trying to enforce good practices (as they see it) for undergrads learning the language. A submission that circumvents this test (especially the example you've shown) is by a student who knows what they are doing, and then this test doesn't really matter for them.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) output of the Clang compiler to validate that a certain member is private or public. For example, for the following code:

```
class test {
public:
    int pub;
private:
    int prv;
};
```

Running this command: `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only t.cpp`

gives the AST dump:

```
TranslationUnitDecl 0x55f6f550e3f8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc>
|-TypedefDecl 0x55f6f550e9b0 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __int128_t '__int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x55f6f550e690 '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x55f6f550ea20 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128'
| `-BuiltinType 0x55f6f550e6b0 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x55f6f550ed68 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __NSConstantString '__NSConstantString_tag'
| `-RecordType 0x55f6f550eb10 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|   `-CXXRecord 0x55f6f550ea78 '__NSConstantString_tag'
|-TypedefDecl 0x55f6f550ee00 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_ms_va_list 'char *'
| `-PointerType 0x55f6f550edc0 'char *'
|   `-BuiltinType 0x55f6f550e490 'char'
|-TypedefDecl 0x55f6f5545bf8 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __builtin_va_list '__va_list_tag [1]'
| `-ConstantArrayType 0x55f6f5545ba0 '__va_list_tag [1]' 1
|   `-RecordType 0x55f6f550eef0 '__va_list_tag'
|     `-CXXRecord 0x55f6f550ee58 '__va_list_tag'
`-CXXRecordDecl 0x55f6f5545c50 <t.cpp:1:1, line:6:1> line:1:7 class test definition
  |-DefinitionData pass_in_registers trivially_copyable trivial literal
  | |-DefaultConstructor exists trivial needs_implicit
  | |-CopyConstructor simple trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
  | |-MoveConstructor exists simple trivial needs_implicit
  | |-CopyAssignment trivial has_const_param needs_implicit implicit_has_const_param
  | |-MoveAssignment exists simple trivial needs_implicit
  | `-Destructor simple irrelevant trivial needs_implicit
  |-CXXRecordDecl 0x55f6f5545d78 <col:1, col:7> col:7 implicit class test
  |-AccessSpecDecl 0x55f6f5545e10 <line:2:1, col:7> col:1 public
  |-FieldDecl 0x55f6f5545e50 <line:3:5, col:9> col:9 pub 'int'
  |-AccessSpecDecl 0x55f6f5545e98 <line:4:1, col:8> col:1 private
  `-FieldDecl 0x55f6f5545ed8 <line:5:5, col:9> col:9 prv 'int'
```

which is quite simple to parse by a script. Or you can use the Clang AST library to create `LibASTMatcher` to validate using data itself as described in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html).

Comment: Thank you! This is wonderful and would work nicely but I am electing to be compiler-independent. I will probably implement this in a future semester.

Answer (score 7):

To append [cigien's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) as I am testing a non-constant object, i.e., `T` is altered during construction of the object, and thus will test at runtime rather than compile time. This just involves removing the `const` keywords:

```
// Check that color is a public member
template<typename T>
auto has_public_color(T &t) -> decltype(t.color, true)
{
    // Returns true if T has a public member named color
    return true;
}
auto has_public_color(...)
{
    return false;
}
```

Then I just insert into my unit testing framework (Boost unit testing) as such:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_cell_no_public_color)
{
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Testing that Cell has no public member of color");
    // Check that Cell has no public color
    BOOST_CHECK(not has_public_color(Cell{}));
}
```

Comment: So your students can just name the (public) field `my_color` and the test passes? What's the point?

Comment: I also do the inverse and check that color exists as a private member. They're just learning how to define classes and I want to enforce some abstraction and encapsulation principles so they write their programs to strict directions. They're more focused on learning the C++ syntax than actual program design.